# Pandas 0.18.1 groupby and resample with multilevel aggregation error

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I just updated pandas from 0.17.1 to 0.18.1 and think I found an issue with the new resample methodology outlined below while altering some preexisting code. According to this documentation df3_resample and df4_resample in my below example should return the same dataframe, however df4_resample throws an exception. This tripped me up for awhile so I figured I would share.

```
Exception: Column(s) A already selected
```

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.0/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-0180-breaking-resample

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/whatsnew.html#groupby-syntax-with-window-and-resample-operations

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,4),
              columns=list('ABCD'),
              index=pd.date_range('2010-01-01 09:00:00', periods=10, freq='s'))
df['item'] = 'item_a' # add column for groupby

# THIS WORKS 
df1_resample = df.groupby('item').resample('2s').agg({'A': np.mean, 'B': np.max}).reset_index()
print df1_resample

# THIS WORKS 
df2_resample = df.resample('2s').agg({'A': {'A_mean': np.mean, 'A_max': np.max}}).reset_index()
print df2_resample

# THIS WORKS 
df3_resample = df.groupby('item').apply(lambda x: x.resample('2s').agg({'A': {'A_mean': np.mean, 'A_max': np.max}})).reset_index()
print df3_resample

# THIS DOESN"T WORKS 
df4_resample = df.groupby('item').resample('2s').agg({'A': {'A_mean': np.mean, 'A_max': np.max}})
print df4_resample
```

Output:

```
 item             level_1         A         B
0  item_a 2010-01-01 09:00:00  0.611660  0.739640 
1  item_a 2010-01-01 09:00:02  0.615876  0.880113
2  item_a 2010-01-01 09:00:04  0.218292  0.441504
3  item_a 2010-01-01 09:00:06  0.753698  0.637787
4  item_a 2010-01-01 09:00:08  0.471272  0.474738
                  index         A          
                         A_mean     A_max
0 2010-01-01 09:00:00  0.611660  0.813038
1 2010-01-01 09:00:02  0.615876  0.994657
2 2010-01-01 09:00:04  0.218292  0.233478
3 2010-01-01 09:00:06  0.753698  0.848107
4 2010-01-01 09:00:08  0.471272  0.610592
     item             level_1         A          
                                 A_mean     A_max
0  item_a 2010-01-01 09:00:00  0.611660  0.813038
1  item_a 2010-01-01 09:00:02  0.615876  0.994657
2  item_a 2010-01-01 09:00:04  0.218292  0.233478
3  item_a 2010-01-01 09:00:06  0.753698  0.848107
4  item_a 2010-01-01 09:00:08  0.471272  0.610592


  File "<some_file.py>", line 29, in <module>
    df4_resample = df.groupby('item').resample('2s').agg({'A': {'A_mean': np.mean, 'A_max': np.max}})

  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\tseries\resample.py", line 293, in aggregate
  result, how = self._aggregate(arg, *args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py", line 505, in _aggregate
    result = list(_agg(arg, _agg_1dim).values())

  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py", line 496, in _agg
    result[fname] = func(fname, agg_how)

  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py", line 479, in _agg_1dim
    return colg.aggregate(how, _level=(_level or 0) + 1)

  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\tseries\resample.py", line 293, in aggregate
    result, how = self._aggregate(arg, *args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py", line 528, in _aggregate
  result = _agg(arg, lambda fname,

  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py", line 496, in _agg
     result[fname] = func(fname, agg_how)

  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py", line 529, in <lambda>
agg_how: _agg_1dim(self._selection, agg_how))

  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py", line 475, in _agg_1dim
  colg = self._gotitem(name, ndim=1, subset=subset)

  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py", line 680, in _gotitem
  groupby=self._groupby[key],

  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py", line 326, in __getitem__
    raise Exception('Column(s) %s already selected' % self._selection)

  Exception: Column(s) A already selected
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why the `resample` doesn't work for this but there is a convenient work-around that doesn't require using lambda. Give this a try:

```
df.groupby([
    'item', pd.Grouper(freq = '2s')
]).agg({
    'A' : ['mean', 'max']
}).rename(columns = {
    'mean' : 'A_mean', 'max' : 'A_max'
}, level = 1).reset_index()
```

[image: output]

Instead of using `.resample('2S')` you can add `pd.Grouper('2s')` to your `groupby()`. It functions the same way for you case. Here is the documentation --> http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18/generated/pandas.Grouper.html

On another note, you should avoid renaming columns with a nested dictionary (it's deprecated) and instead use the actual `.rename()` function.